# Visual Studio's "Generate Sample XML" Size Limit?

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I am using [Visual Studio's "Generate Sample XML"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821/1175496) to achieve this transformation:

XSD -> (Sample) XML

I know it is called "sample". I appreciate "samples" won't have meaningful values; just a value that satisfies the XSD constraints

- i.e. 0 satisfies `xsd:integer` datatype constraint,
- i.e. 3 tags are used to satisfy both `1..*` and `0..*` sequence/minOccurs/maxoccurs constraints
- and [other conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25435315/1175496)

However, when I click "Generate Sample XML", the resulting XML doesn't contain **(at least one) tag for all the elements defined in XSD.**

- I want an "exhaustive" XML; that is, resulting XML contains a tag for all elements defined in the XSD.

Specifically here are my circumstances:

- My XSD has an `<xsd:sequence>` which allows for a series of `0..*` and `1..*` elements.
- Each of these elements is quite complex; each of these elements produces sample XML that is on average ~ 270 lines long.
- This `<xsd: sequence>` allows for 120 of these elements; each of which is unique.
- That means, the sample XML for this  `<xsd: sequence>` element could be 270 * 120 = **32,400 lines of resulting XML.**

What I'm finding is that Generate Sample XML will **not** produce a document **longer than 6,000 lines of XML.**

This means it does not produce an "exhaustive" XML; it limits the output sample XML to only the first 30 tags (*in the order they were listed as children of* the  `<xsd: sequence>` in the XSD ** (see below) -- **even if this means the resulting XML is invalid [since it could omit *required* elements]**);

the remaining 120-30 = **90** elements defined in the XSD are **excluded from the output sample XML.**

Can anyone explain why? Is it user-error? Is there a workaround? No need to recommend other tools if they are already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17106/1175496).

I can move this question to superuser if that's more appropriate.

** I believe the order in which the elements are referenced as children of `<xsd:sequence>` is important; when I rearranged this order (for instance, moving children 51-53 to become first children; 1-3; then these elements included in the ~6,000 line output, but the other elements they displaced were excluded)